# Only shadow been rendered

Tags: rendering, shadows

I may have some wrong setting in my rendering, but i cannot find it out.

No material is missing, I copied this mesh from one of my other project, it works fine, but working weirdly in this one.

Here is the render and the setting.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you provide the file to see some other details that we can't see in the images.

Comment: I'd be surprised this is about rendering settings. Have you look at the object state in the outliner?

Comment: update the outliner.